# Fixing 3rd Party Broken Enum class in JAR

Tags: java, jar, enums

I'm using a 3rd party JAR which is trying parse an enum field but the Enum class is missing out one of the enums.
What would be the easiest way of me to fix the Enum class without the source code?

Comment: How do you know its missing one of the enums without the source code?

Comment: I can see the list in the Eclipse byte code viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are hoping for.

1. unzip the jar file (jar files are zip files).
2. run javap (included with the jdk) to produce some source code for the class in question.
3. add the required enum value(s).
4. compile the modified class
5. rebuild the jar.

Option 2:
contact the source of the 3rd party jar to see if they have a fix for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think any quick fix is going to make it difficult to maintain in the future, so the easiest way is to contact the vendor.

Comment: they are several months away from a release

Comment: Thats frustrating - your options are to decompile the class then recompile the jar. Another option might be to decompile the class, then place it in front of the 3-rd party jar in the class path. Then when the new version comes along just remove your version of the class

Comment: Can I place it in front in the class path when using maven?

Comment: Im unsure - I know its a right hack but your only wanting to use this temporarily so try lib\ext - but make sure you remember its there